# Google Sheets query in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets, beautifulsoup, google-sheets-api

I have a Google sheet that grabs data from a website using the =IMPORTXML function. I also have a Python script that grabs data from the Google sheet. The whole thing is working, but I'm now trying to streamline it. This whole thing started as a manual process in Google Sheets. It's now automated, but it's not pretty.

Two specific questions:

1) What is the best way to scrape a website using Python? I'd like to get this all running in a single script. Would something like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) be a good solution?

2) Currently the query to the google API is coded to run separately each query (it's not a sub function, but I'd like to turn it into one). It essentially copies the [quickstart script](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python):

```
spreadsheetId = 'xxxx'
rangeName = 'xxxx'
result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,range=rangeName).execute()
values = result.get('values', [])
variable = ''
for row in values:
    variable = '%s' % (row[0])
if variable != storedVariable:
    print ('Condition not met...')
    return;
#Do a thing
```

My code has various versions of setting a variable, checking it against a stored value, and proceeding if the correct conditions exist. Is there an easier way to parse the values returned from the API call so that it's set as a variable?

Answer (score 0):

1. BeautifulSoup will work well for scraping data as long as the page is completely static. For most webpages you'll need to be able interact with the page to get to the data you need or iterate through multiple pages. Selenium is great for these situations.
2. I don't have a better solution for this question. The google-api-python-client library is cumbersome. It looks like gspread used to be a good alternative with more features, but it hasn't been updated for almost a year and seems to have fallen behind the google library.